# while loop and range

Tags: python, while-loop, range

How to print all numbers in range If num_1 is smaller than num_2

Comment: You have a while loop on `i`, but you don't change `i` within the loop.  That's a recipe for an infinite loop.

Comment: It's not clear to me how you intend for the code to work. In your own words, what do you think a `while` loop *is*, and how does it work? You have two loops in your code. How many times do you intend for each one to run, and why? Where you have, for example, `while num_1 < num_2 :`, is it your intent that the values of `num_1` and/or `num_2` should *change* while the loop is running? If so, how? If not, then why would the condition ever have a different result?

Answer (score 0):

First of all `i in range(num_1, num_2)` returns type `bool`, so your `while` loop will either block or skip.

You can use `for` instead of `while`, it will traverse the `range(num_1, num_2)`

The [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range) function can pass in the `step` parameter to control the step size, negative numbers are reverse

Use `while`:

```py
num_1 = int(input("First number : "))
num_2 = int(input("Second number : "))
if num_1 < num_2:
    step = 1
else:
    step = -1
r = range(num_1, num_2, step)

flag = num_2 - num_1
i = 0
while i != flag:
    if r[i] % 3 == 0:
        print(f"i: {i}, v: {r[i]}")
    i += step

else:
    print('')
```

Demo:

```
First number : 1
Second number : 11
i: 2, v: 3
i: 5, v: 6
i: 8, v: 9


First number : 11
Second number : 1
i: -2, v: 3
i: -5, v: 6
i: -8, v: 9
```

Use `for`:

```py
num_1 = int(input("First number : "))
num_2 = int(input("Second number : "))
if num_1 < num_2:
    step = 1
else:
    step = -1
for i in range(num_1, num_2, step):
    if i % 3 == 0:
        print(i)

print('')
```

Demo:

```
First number : 1
Second number : 11
3
6
9


First number : 11
Second number : 1
9
6
3
```

Comment: Thank you!! I agree with you that decision with for is much better but I have to  solve it with while loop and how to write about step decreased without for range?

Comment: @Zen I made a change, is this what you want?

Comment: That's great! I save this decision for future because some things I don't know yet. Is there much simplier decision? How is it possible to solve without abs function?

Comment: @Zen I made changes, you can try again.

Comment: I changed code in my question and I don't know how to add condition if num1 is bigger than num2. Could you please help with that ?

Comment: @Zen `Suggested edit queue is full`. If my answer is what you want, then you can try to get familiar with it and try to figure it out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of syntax issues (e.g. indentation). Fixing them up, the following should work:

```py
num_1 = int(input("First number : "))
num_2 = int(input("Second number : "))
i = num_1
while i in range(num_1, num2):
    if i % 3 ==0:
        print(i)
    i += 1
```

To handle changing the order of iteration depending on the values of `num_1` and `num_2` (as asked in a comment), you can do the following:

```py
num_1 = int(input("First number : "))
num_2 = int(input("Second number : "))

if num_1 < num_2:
    for i in range(num_1, num_2):
        if i % 3 == 0:
            print(i)
else:
    for i in range(num_1, num_2 - 1, -1):
        if i % 3 == 0:
            print(i)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But how to check ' If num_1 is bigger than num_2 then step should be increased and opposite' ? I should write in range(num_1, num2, -1) and write this condition in else?

Comment: @Zen Added to the original answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a while loop for this.  If you want all numbers divisible by three within a given range, you can do this in a single line of code (excluding the inputs):

```py
a = 0
b = 100

l = [x for x in range(a, b) if x%3 == 0]
```

The result would be:

```
[0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39, 42, 45, 48, 51, 54, 57, 60, 63, 66, 69, 72, 75, 78, 81, 84, 87, 90, 93, 96, 99]
```

You could also make this a function for better reuse:

```py
def get_divisible_numbers(a, b, divisor):
    """
    Returns a list of all numbers between two numbers (a and b where a < b) that are divisible by a given number (divisor).
    """
    return [x for x in range(a, b) if x%divisor == 0]
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! I will get that in mind but I just start to learn by myself and it interested me how to solve with only while loop..

Comment: Welcome to the community!  I would not recommend a while loop for this use case.  A list comprehension as shown in the example will be faster than a for loop and that would be faster than a while loop.  If this helped, please consider accepting the answer so others can find it when they view this post.  Thanks and happy learning!

Comment: Note: This will only work if a < b.

Answer (score 0):

```
num_1 = int(input("First number : "))
num_2 = int(input("Second number : "))
divider = 3
if num_2 < num_1:
    num_1, num_2 = num_2, num_1  # swap the first and second numbers
while num_2 >= num_1:
    if num_1 % 3 == 0:  # find the first number divisible by 3
        while num_2 >= num_1:
            print(num_1)
            num_1 += divider
    num_1 += 1
```

Output:

```
First number : 17
Second number : -2
0
3
6
9
12
15
```